# SendGrid not working - ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendgrid

I'm trying to use SendGrid to send an email confirmation. It just does not seem to be working.

Here is my code in the controller:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a confirmation email with SendGrid
    /// </summary>
    static async Task SendMemberConfirmation(ApplicationUser currentUser)
    {

        var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_APIKEY");
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);

        var from = new EmailAddress("membership@cccsports.com", "CCC Sports");
        var subject = "CCC Sports - Membership Confirmation";

        var to = new EmailAddress(currentUser.Email, currentUser.FirstName + " " + currentUser.LastName);

        var htmlContent = "<h1>CCC Sports Membership Confirmation</h1>";
        var plainTextContent = "Thank you " + currentUser.FirstName + "! " + "Your membership has been created! you will be billed anually depending on your membership type.";

        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, null, htmlContent);

        msg.AddContent(MimeType.Html, "<br /> <ul> <li>Adult: £20</li> <li>Juvenile: £15</li> <li>Family: £75</li>");

        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

    }
```

I call this SendMemberConfirmation async in another async method:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult>
AddToMember(IEnumerable<string> Roles)
    {
        //...

        await SendMemberConfirmation(currentUser);
    }
```

I have made an environment variable called SENDGRID_APIKEY with the key. So i just don't know what's going on, its not sending any email and it's there is no requests on my SendGrid dashboard.

Update: I set a break point and it says SendGridClient.cs not found. I tired updating SendGrid in the package manager, but it still does not seem to work.

Comment: try wrapping the var response.. in a try catch block. I've had issues with SendGrid sending it and bouncing off their mail servers because of routing or a bad key or a million other things.

Comment: @ThomasTaylor Thanks, I gave that a try but it still doesn't seem to be working. Is there something I might have missed? Do I need to provide credentials or something?

Comment: did you see if an exception was triggered?